# Django/DRF GET list of objects including object with FK to that object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an API endpoint that returns a list of objects (Orders).

```
class Order(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

Each of these Orders also has multiple associated Statuses, which acts similar to tracking the location of a package. A new one is created whenever the status changes, with the new status and a timestamp.

```
class OrderStatus(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order_statuses")
```

When I query a list of the current Orders, I want to return the most recent OrderStatus associated with it.  Such as this:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "item_name": "Something",
            "order_status": {
                "status": "Processing"
                "timestamp": "2023-09-25T12:31:12Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "item_name": "Other Thing",
            "order_status": {
                "status": "Completed"
                "timestamp": "2023-08-15T10:41:32Z"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried using `prefetch_related()` in my View, but that seems to be for the reverse situation (When the query is for the object that has the FK in it's class definition - which here would be if I wanted to list the fields on Order when I query for the OrderStatus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a read only method in your order serializer then assign it the latest status related to the order.

```py
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_status = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True, method_name="get_order_status")

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["id", "item_name", "order_status"]

    def get_order_status(self, obj):
        latest_status = OrderStatus.objects.filter(order=obj).latest("timestamp")
        return OrderStatusSerializer(latest_status).data
```

Comment: Pretty close! Thanks! I had to make the following changes: The `SerializerMethodField` needs `method_name="get_order_status"` and the returned response should be `return OrderStatusSerializer(latest_status).data`

Also this will fail if an Order does not have a Status object associated, but that just requires a Try/Except to catch the error.

Comment: If you want to update your response accordingly I will happily accept the answer!

Comment: @BrianC edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `.values()` method to the end of your `QuerySet`, which will return all the fields of the specified model, including the id field.

@see - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#values (*Django 3.2*)